# Mouse Logger is bug

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging, mouse

Well I have this big code:

http://pastebin.com/ADwMqzFb

The problem when I press F8 and It start to save all the clicks on the Mouse Logger.txt file

I have a problem:

```
Mouse Left Down At: (518,72))7,301)
```

The output only have one line. And is bug as you can see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert `File.Open(PathArchivo, FileMode.Open)` into `File.Open(PathArchivo, FileMode.Append)`. Also you should bring something else into account to write new lines. Either `strStreamWriter.WriteLine("anything")` or `& Environment.NewLine` after each string.

Comment: I have one problem, the Handles call itself automatically and I don't have press F8... What can I do?

Comment: You are welcome. I am not getting this last point. Could you please explain it better? (o dilo en español vía mensaje personal si te resulta más fácil)

Comment: Ah vale mucho mejor XD Ehm a ver, que sin pulsar el F8 los Handlers ya están activados... :( PD: Por aquí hay mensajes privados?

Comment: Me refería en plan mensaje personal (para ser sincero no sé si se puede hacer), porque aquí no dejan hablar en español y van a dar el toque. Pero bueno... sigo sin entender lo que quieres decir con los handlers están activados. Quieres decir que se llama a los handler methods antes de que el usuario pulse una tecla?

Comment: Si bueno como puedes ver aquí: Public Sub Key_Listener(ByVal key As String)
 
        If key = "{F8}" Then
            AddHandler...

Esos Handlers están activados siempre y se supone que hasta que no pulses F8 no se activan...

Comment: Déjame ejecutar tu código y ya te digo.

Comment: (sigo en inglés pa evitar problemas) The code is pretty big and additionally I get an error (running as winforms under VS 2010) right at the start ("Could not set keyboard hook"). It seems like the only way to "activate" the handlers is Key_Listener, set a break point there to understand why this part is reached before the user presses F8. Without executing the code I cannot really tell but shouldn't be too difficult to find out the reason and avoid this situation. In any case I guess that you should post another question to answer this issue :)

Comment: You have to uncheck that: Project -> [Project Name] Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck “Enable the Visual Studio hosting process”

Comment: I did that and the program is really unstable. It makes difficult even running a simple step-by-step execution. Why are you saying that the handlers are active? The corresponding code (under f8) is not reached and neither the associated methods are raised. In any case, I think that this code needs lots of improvements to be more or less "controllable" (I guess that you have got it from somewhere). And I insist: this is a completely different story and you should post a new question. Although I recommend to restart the code step by step and understand how each bit works.